# Getting data out from Prismic based on type and value of a field

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, prismic.io

My question would be how is it possible to get data out from Prismic based on type and value of a field, and order it based on another field in Vue 3 with the Composition API.

For example, let's say we have a custom type for football players. A player has a position dropdown field, where you can select their position, and a field for their jersey number.

```js
const { data: players } = useAllPrismicDocumentsByType("player")
```

I understand that this is a basic way to fetch the data, but how would i add filtering and the order? For example in the document, the position field has to be Goalkeeper, so i would only get the Goalkeepers out, and order them based on their jersey number (ascending).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would add filters and orderings to your Prismic query:

```
import * as prismic from "@prismicio/client";

const { data: players } = useAllPrismicDocumentsByType("player", {
  filters: [
    prismic.filter.at("my.player.position", "Goalkeeper")
  ],
  orderings: [
    { field: "my.player.number", direction: "asc" }
  ]
})
```

- [See the filters documentation](https://prismic.io/docs/technical-reference/prismicio-client#query-filters) to learn more about filtering query responses.
- [See the orderings documentation](https://prismic.io/docs/technical-reference/prismicio-client#query-methods-params) to learn more about sorting query responses.

Comment: So I would need to install the prismicio/client separately? (i have prismicio/vue installed only as of now)

Comment: Yes, you will need the `@prismicio/client` package installed. You should already have it installed since it is a dependency of `@prismicio/vue`, but it is good practice to install it explicitly since you will be importing the package in your code.